# Mysql: get data where multiple foreign keys hit condition

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

`r_rec` where the neccessary thing is the primary `id`

and

`r_fibu` where `i_rec` is the foreign key to `rec` and `sh` filled with `h` or `s`.

I want to do a query to find every `id` from `rec` where `r_fibu` has more than one dataset where `sh` = h but I can't figure out the query needed.

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT r.id
FROM `r_rec` AS r
INNER JOIN r_fibu AS f ON r.id = f.i_rec
WHERE f.sh = 'h'
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2
```

Comment: Can you add your table definitions and some example data? Preferably in a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Have you created these tables? The naming is somewhat obscure

Comment: @DavidK-J no, that's from a collegue of mine, the tablenames are german shortnames, in german it's understandable, but not well named, that's totally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `count` per `r.id` you need a `group by`

```
SELECT r.id,count(*) as tot
FROM `r_rec` AS r
INNER JOIN r_fibu AS f ON r.id = f.i_rec
WHERE f.sh = 'h'
group by r.id
having tot >=2
```

Comment: You don't need the count in the result set

Comment: I know its not needed, but just to get a glace of what count is getting returned per id I added that.

Comment: Ah, that's what I missed. Thank you very much!